# Implement static nested class' interface in outer class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-fragments, nested-class

I am writing an android class, and I have found that a good way to communicate between fragments and activities is by way of listeners, which define interfaces. In my code, I have defined a static fragment class inside of my main activity. I want to implement the fragment's interface in the outer class, but I can't seem to get the outer class to cleanly implement this code. I know how to write the implementation. The problem is actually declaring that the activity should implement this interface. How do I accomplish this? Code below

```
public class TransferMain extends FragmentActivity implements ServiceConnection,
    ActionBar.TabListener, MainTransferFragment.OnTransferActionListener {
```

MainTransferFragment is the nested class of TransferMain. The declaration shown currently results in an error, as OnTransferActionListener requires that the entire class identifier be named. E.g. 
TransferMain.MainTransferFragment.OnTransferActionListener.

However, when declared as below, java claims cyclic inheritance, which throws an error.

```
public class TransferMain extends FragmentActivity implements ServiceConnection,
    ActionBar.TabListener, TransferMain.MainTransferFragment.OnTransferActionListener
```

What's the move Stack?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993560/why-is-java-prohibiting-inheritance-of-inner-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your fragment to a separate file.

Refer to this answer: [Cyclic inheritance when implementing inner interface in enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811904/cyclic-inheritance-when-implementing-inner-interface-in-enum)